# Oracle functions' optimiser

Tags: oracle, optimization

I have a query like:

```
SELECT id, value
FROM very_large_table -- over 5 million records 
WHERE foo(value) > 5 AND boo(value) IS NOT NULL
```

Assume that `foo` and `boo` are functions, that also makes a lot of selects on super large table without indexes (so it's execution costs a lot).

I (as a programmer) know, that `foo` in 99% time returns more than 5, but `boo` is 99,9% returns `NULL`.
It's obvious, that first of all `boo` should be calculated. And if it's `NULL`, we don't want this row in the result set. So we DON'T need to calculate `foo`, because `boo` is already `NULL`.

Are there any packages/articles on this theme, because, if I'm doing right - oracle doen't do this kind of optimization

---

The above is just a sample.  In my case there are a lot of functions (~50) and I'm using them in various selects in various combinations. So rewriting the functions is not really and option becuse in real situation a have a lot of them: i just wanted to show that these requests are realy slow. I'm just thinkin of some kind of optimizer (in addition to oracle's one)

Answer (score 7):

Oracle CAN do this sort of optimization but needs to be spoon fed
It is called the [Oracle Extensible Optimizer](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28425/ext_optimizer.htm) and [associate statistics](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4006.htm#SQLRF01106)

But the easy way to do it in this case is something like this

```
where case when boo(value) is null then 0 else foo(value) end > 5
```

which forces the boo function to be evaluated before the foo.

The advanced stuff would be applicable if you don't have control over the query (eg using some BI tool). Another reason is if you have a bunch of coders where it would be excessive to develop that sort of understanding and it is easier to have one or two 'database guys' manage that aspect of things.

Comment: Would `NVL2( boo(value), foo(value), 0) > 5` be a slightly more succinct way of saying the same thing?

Comment: @eaolson: Unfortunately, `NVL` and `NVL2` always execute **all** parameters before returning, so `NVL2( boo(value), foo(value), woo(value))` always executes `boo`, `foo` and `woo`.

Comment: Ah. It looks like `CASE` and `DECODE` short-circuit, but those two don't.

Answer (score 2):

Just write function `boofoo` that runs `boo`, then `foo` only if `boo` was not null.

And to tune that further, you could add a function-based index on that table/column:

```
create index vlt_boofoo on very_large_table (boofoo(value));
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mat! I can't rewrite because in my case there are a lot of functions (~50) and I'm using them in various selects in various combinations. Thanks for an advice about index, but in real situation a have a lot of indexes: i just wanted to show that these requests are realy slow. I'm just thinkin of some kind of optimizer (in addition to oracle's one).

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using Oracle 11 Enterprise, [Result Cache](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r1/prod/perform/rescache/res_cache.htm) could help. This would cache the results of your functions once executed, and would not execute them again unless the data in the underlying tables changes.

---

If this does not work, you could try to replace your functions by `VIEW`s to that tables (assuming that you call your functions from more than one place - otherwise you could just join your tables).

This would allow to join these views instead of using the functions, which might allow the optimizer to query your big tables only once instead of once in each call of your functions.

So instead of

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo( in_value IN very_large_table.value%TYPE )
  RETURN PLS_INTEGER
AS
  v_count PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO v_count
  FROM some_other_large_table
  WHERE value = in_value;

  RETURN v_count;
END foo;
```

you could

```
CREATE VIEW view_foo AS
  SELECT value, COUNT(*)
  FROM some_other_large_table
  GROUP BY value;
```

and join that

```
SELECT t.id, t.value
FROM very_large_table t -- over 5 million records
JOIN view_foo foo ON ( foo.value = t.value )
JOIN view_boo ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I once worked on a similar problem.  In my case I only had one function but it was a wicked one: the application was for name-matching and the function returned a score indicating the similarity between a row's value and the user input.  Some names were very common or matched many different variants and so returned thousands of rows, others would return a handful or non at all.  The table was huge, and no scope for indexing because we couldn't possibly map all the possible user inputs.

There are a number of alternative mechanisms for optimizing besides indexes.

1. **Parallel query.**  A brute force solution which works well if your database server has lots of CPUs and you don't have many users who want to query the table simultaneously.  Requires Enterprise Edition license.
2. **Partitioning.**  If you have other criteria to filter your query (creation date or something) then you might be able to apply Partition pruning to reduce the query's scope.  Partitioning is not an automatic performance gain: it is primarily a management option and can degrade the performance of queries which go against the grain of the partition key. Requires Enterprise Edition license plus the Partitioning Option, so *expensive*.
3. **Server Result Set caching.**  In 11g we can store the results of query/sub-query or a function in memory; we pay the cost of executing it once and all subsequent queries get the result set back immediately.  This is good for deterministic functions and slowly changing tables.  [Find out more](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/memory.htm#BGBEEFBE).  It trades memory for performance.  Requires 11g and Enterprise Edition license.
4. **Materialized views.**  We can use MViews to pre-calculate the results of certain queries and the optimizer will automatically use them through the QUERY REWRITE functionality.  Again this works best with slowly-changing tables. It trades disk space for performance.  Requires Enterprise Edition license.
5. **Tokenizing**.  Some of your values may have common elements which relate to the value returned by the function.  For instance a value which starts with 'Z' is never going to have a `FOO()` score greater than 4.  So you can extract those tokens - either in separate tables which you use in joins or as columns (in 11g as virtual columns) which you can index.  You need to add those token filters to the query, perhaps dynamically. Obviously this will only work for certain kinds of data.  Available in all editions.
6. **Index other columns**.  A poor man's partitioning, but if you have other columns which are used in the query consider whether any of them can be used to constrain the result set before applying your functions. Available in all editions.
7. **Function-based indexes.**  I know you have already discounted this option but you should reconsider.  You don't need to build indexes for every function.  In the example you give `BOO()` filters out most of the rows and `FOO()` hardly any.  Thus an index on `BOO()` would be highly optimal and an index on `FOO()` worse than useless.  So, look at your functions: determine which ones are highly selective and are used most often, and build function-based indexes for them.  Available in all editions.

As you can see, a lot of these optimizations require the Enterprise Edition.  Well, Oracle wants you to spring for the more expensive license, that's why they restrict the cool features.  The optimizations available in the Standard Edition require more effort on our part.

How did I solve my problem?  Well I was on 9i, so Result Set Caching was not available to me, but that was the one I really wanted.  Unfortunately I had way too many concurrent users for parallel query to be feasible.  My final solution was a mixture of Tokenizing and complicated indexing structures.